# SQL how to get informations in result set only latest date?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one to many, we'll call them a and b, in b many there's a date, I would like a result set like so:

```
select a.*, b.all the columns but only for the latest date
where a.id = b.foreign_key_to_a
```

how would you suggest to do it?

edit:
I forgot to mention I expect a result set longer than one, so is for very record in a that it should check it's latest date

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you need, but it sounds like this is a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] type of question. Can you take a look at some answers to questions with that tag and see if it is related to your question? If not, please edit your question and show an example of some data and what you expect the result to be.

Comment: example, I want to view a list of something, each something has height and width, each something has n somethingelse, each somethingelse has color and date, for each element in my list I want: height, width, (color of the latest date), it's a very specific case and it's more easy to explain like this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've understood your question correctly but you could try something like this:

```
SELECT a.*,b.* from a join b on a.pk=b.fk
where b.date = (select max(date) from date)
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I expect a result set longer than one, so is for very record in a that it should check it's latest date

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I still don't understand, maybe you could provide an example with dummy data? Or maybe, clearer wording would help immensely.